# @media doesn't work in stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I don't want to show an image when the screen size is too small. Here I use @media to perform this task. The image has an id **mpImage**

```
#mpImage
  padding-top: 40

  @media (min-width: 480)
    display: none
```

But it doesn't have any response.

Further information:
index.jade:

```
head
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
    .carousel
        img#mpImage(src="/images/mainP1.gif")
        .carousel-caption
            h1 Title
```

style.styl:

```
.carousel
  height: 500
  background-color: #888
#mpImage
  padding-top: 50
  @media screen and (max-width: 480)
    display: none
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use some type of unit. It's not JavaScript.

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/38a098554612f43cdda74d2a5e595f0a

For fun, here is how you would use a media query with a variable

```
$break-point-1 = '(min-width: 600px)'

html
    background: red
    @media $break-point-1
        background: blue
    @media (min-width: 1000px)
        background: green
    @media (min-width: 1400px)
        background: lightgreen
```

Comment: Another thought - is that you shouldn't load the image unless the screen is large enough, as opposed to just hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
.carousel
  height: 500
  background-color: #888
#mpImage
  padding-top: 50
@media screen and (max-width: 480)
  #mpImage
     display: none
```

The style inside min-width: 480 will only apply if your screen is bigger than 480px, max-width: 480 will apply for screen smaller than 480px

Comment: It's still do not work. Strange. I follow the documentation on stylus about @media but nothing appear.

Comment: Can you share your html and css in a fiddle ?

Comment: Sure. By the way, I open the website with safari.

Comment: Could you try putting your @media around your #mpImage selector?

Comment: No. I read the documentation of stylus from here http://stylus-lang.com/docs/media.html

Comment: Sorry I don't know stylus or jade. I can't help you more. Try to look what's happening in the browser inspector